# create a dictionary from two lists based on correct indexing

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, python-2.7

I have two arrays, lets say L1 and L2 takes the following form.

```
L1 = array([2, 3, 5, 2, 5, 2, 3])
L2 = array([1.2, 3.3, 5.7, 1.6, 5.5, 1.5, 3.4])
```

Now I want to create a dictionary in the following form;

```
dict_ = {2: [1.2, 1.6, 1.5], 3: [3.3, 3.4], 5: [5.7, 5.5]}
```

This is what I did;

```
dict_ = {}

for ts, te in zip(L1, L2):
  if ts not in dict_.keys():
    dict_[ts] = ts
    dict_.update({ts: te})  

  if ts in dict_.keys():
    dict_[ts] = [dict_[ts], te]
```

The format I received is not very elegant.. and not as I expected.

Comment: `if ts not in dict_: dict_[ts] = []; dict_[ts].append(te)`

Comment: Or: `dict_.setdefault(ts, []).append(te)`

Comment: Are you using numpy?

Comment: may I ask what you mean by "correct indexing"? and what is the relation between L1, L2 and your desired dictionary?

Comment: yes I use numpy

Comment: Alternatively, you could try [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), which uses a default value type. That way, you can append things to the list without needing to initialize the key

Comment: @learner the article you referenced explains why you **shouldn't** use your proposal

Comment: @bn_In Thanks for correcting me. Here is the correct snippet that I tested successfully: x={k:[] for k in set(L1)}

for ts, te in zip(L1, L2):
    if not te in x[ts]:
        x[ts].append(te)